# Sphinx Error Installation In Windows 8

Tags: php, python, cmd, sphinx

Hi followed this article

http://www.crankberryblog.com/2011/intalling-sphinx-on-wamp-localhost-windows

for installation on windows 8 but while entring this line

Once there launched the indexer to build the index by typing in indexer.exe –config c:\sphinx\bin\sphinx.conf test1

I get the error in cmd

ERROR:Malformed or unknown option near '-uconfig'...

---

I have tried many articles,but could nt get the result.
Also Is it required to install python for this?
Please help..Its been two days but all in vain...
Also is it easier to install in ubuntu?

Comment: The information you have provided is unclear. e.g. " but while entring this line ", what line? I don't know whether python is required, but you could try installing it. Relative ease of installation on Ubuntu is probably a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a simply - (a plain hyphen)

In your post above, you have a unicode hyphen. Probably because you copy/pasted it from the article that used such a hyphen. Perhaps its been pasted via MSWord or similar that has auto-correct on.

Try just typing the command. Not copy/pasting.

> Also is it easier to install in ubuntu?

Not necesserily easier, because if you dont have abny more of ubuntu, then it will still be 'hard'. But in general it is 'more reliable'

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem like this today. Maybe this will help you out.

After getting into `indexer.exe` in `cmd` a list of options will show. Actually at the bottom of that list it gives an example how to use the options.

Type:

`indexer --config c:\sphinx\bin\sphinx.conf test1`

Use both dashes.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Instead of **indexer.exe** use **indexer**:

```
indexer --config c:\sphinx\bin\sphinx.conf test1
```